# A Security Stack Exchange CTF team

Tags: discussion, ctf

**Updates:**

- Added first challenge to prepare
- We have a CTFTime team, [secse](https://ctftime.org/team/3585/). Please join this.
- We communicate over [Slack](http://sec-ctf.slack.com/). To get an invitation to the group you can contact [Benoit Esnard](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/76718/benoit-esnard), [HamZa](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/25859/hamza), [Xavier59](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/110133/xavier59), [Arminius](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/95381/arminius) or any other active team member. (We will need to know an email address to send the invitation to and a reference to your Security.SE profile.)

### CTF TIME

[CTF Time](http://ctftime.org/) is a website dedicated to CTF challenges. We will subscribe a team and we will...

[image]

There are basically 4 types of challenges:

- Exploiting
- Web
- Reversing
- Forensics

And then there are also the occasional misc challenges. So basically we will have people working on each of the categories. Preferably a more experienced person in the field with less experienced people in the field so we can factor in some learning. To be good we should have about 4 people/challenge. A team of 16 people would be ideal. We can rotate the team

### Basic Requierements

- **Have at least 400 rep on security.SE or have more than a combined 2000 rep on your network profile in related fields (Crypto, Stack Overflow, Webmasters, Server Fault, Reverse Engineering ...). Sites in an unrelated field (Arqade, The Workplace, etc.) do not count!**
- Understanding of basic TCP/IP
- Understanding of at least 1 programming (Java, C, C++, C#) and 1 scripting language (preferably, PHP, Python, Perl or Ruby)
- Have basic understanding of at least one of the topics (knowing what things like XSS or SQL injection are)

### Things we need

(I should be able to provide this on my personal systems, but should SE have something like this it  would be nice)

- IRC server with a private channel or a private chatroom on SE
- A Wiki to centralize all of our learnings.

### How much time will this take of me?

You have to know most CTF's last 2 days, to be able to complete a challenge you will need to be able to commit around 4 - 6 hours at least.

### Team

This is a team effort, don't expect this thing to be easy, it isn't. It will take a lot of time and might even give you some frustration, but when you are able to decipher a challenge you will be having a digital orgasm.

[image]

### Code of Conduct

- Common sense
- Don't do or share anything illegal
- Always follow the CTF challenges rules

Comment: Excellent idea. Sadly I'd be no use at this sort of thing any more.

Comment: @RoryAlsop we can use a coordinator :3?

Comment: @RoryAlsop you can be team manager! :-)

Comment: I'd be keen but I'm a serious noob. I'd do way more learning than helping :)

Comment: I'd be interested in joining in, but my usefulness would largely depend on the nature of the challenges. Most of them (in my experience) tend to be reliant on development for Linux platforms, which I suck at.

Comment: I have some experience and would be glad to participate.

Comment: I'd be interested depending on time and skill commitments needed

Comment: I work as a Linux sysadmin and have little to offer in the way of security expertise. That said, I'm very eager to learn and would love to be part of this.

Comment: As pentesting goes, I'm still pretty much in the n00b stage.  But, I welcome a chance to learn.  Let me know what I can do to help!

Comment: I have no pentesting/blackhat or forensic experience, and I really need to work on that. I'd like to participate, if I can find the time.

Comment: I don't know how much time I could put towards such a thing, but it would be interesting to do something a bit more team oriented than messing around with hackthissite.org.  Being a software architect, I don't get a whole lot of chances lately to practice.

Comment: I'd like to get in on this.  Is it possible?

Comment: I would also like to participate.

Comment: I'd quite like to get involved, but can I be like on the bench? As in, I don't always know what my time commitments are going to be like but I'd be happy to help out if I am free? (I might even change my name back to Ninefingers for this).

Comment: This sounds like fun. I've got mostly C# and C knowledge, and TCP/IP knowledge (used to work as a network admin).
My security-related skills are in reverse engineering and binary exploit development (have found/reported holes in a couple things).

Comment: @DinuSmădu I added you to the team

Comment: Is anything more happening with this or has it more or less died?

Comment: There aren't any CTF's atm and I'm a bit busy atm :p

Comment: Chatted a bit with RoryAlsop about this. I'm definitely interested; and I do satisfy the criteria (would need to brush up on TCP/IP though). I know about web security(XSS/etc), basic SQL injection, and I know my way around *nix systems. I speak Python, PHP ,C, Java, and C++ (and JS). Could I be added? :)

Comment: Added you to the list :)

Comment: @LucasKauffman What about users on RE.SE? For example, [this guy](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/users/189/asheeshr) (he's interested in joining)

Comment: I don't mind joining. I know PHP well, I am familiar with Java and C.

Comment: I wants to play! PHP, XSS , Sqli, and finding all teh broken things are my strengths. Can I haz team?

Comment: Sounds like a fun, if I would know about it earlier. Certainly worth trying next year.

Comment: @LucasKauffman [Are you the admin for the team](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/151?m=43500667#43500667)? There are some team membership requests pending. :)

Comment: @JeffFerland Are you, by any chance, our CTFtime's team admin?

Comment: Is the team still active? I'm almost at 400 now.

Answer (score 10):

**Preparing Challenges:**

- This is the first challenge to prepare, it's very easy and requires some very basic crypto and scripting skills. What you need to do is to complete the blowfish level 1 of smash the stack. Go to `ssh level1@blowfish.smashthestack.org -p 22 passwd: level1`. I will submit the solution by the weekend. It took me about 1 hour to solve it, of which mostly was debugging my script. [Solution is here](https://cloud101.eu/blog/2013/01/13/smashthestack-org-blowfish-level-1/).

Sign in on ctftime.org and apply to https://ctftime.org/team/ look for "security.se"

**Upcoming CTF**

- http://ghostintheshellcode.com/ (15th February but we can already do the teaser)

Comment: For those who don't have access to SSH directly.  The description of the challenge is that "GungJnfRnfl" is a simple substitution cypher of the password for Level 2.

Comment: Got it in about 15 minutes by hand. It was simple.:)

Comment: A couple of minutes using an online script. 
P.S. @Rory Alsop: I am now old enough to join the team (+400Rep) :).

Comment: You don't want to know how fast I cracked that.

Comment: `Any or all uses of this system and all files on this system may be intercepted, monitored, recorded, copied, audited, inspected, and disclosed to law enforcement personnel, as well as authorized officials of other agencies, both domestic and foreign. By using this system, the user consents to such interception, monitoring, recording, copying, auditing, inspection, and disclosure at the discretion of Sawbox Inc.`

Comment: `Unauthorized or improper use of this system may result in administrative disciplinary action and civil and criminal penalties. By continuing to use this system you indicate your awareness of and consent to these terms and conditions of use. LOG OFF IMMEDIATELY if you do not agree to the conditions stated in
this warning.`

Comment: but http://smashthestack.org appears to be working normally, I am thinking this ssh server no longer works?

Answer (score 6):

When we get to doing any competitions, I'll create a private channel for the team. I'm leaning toward retroactively putting the channels to "open" at the end of competitions for the sake of sharing knowledge but still giving us a way to compete effectively.

If we don't open things up at the end, it'll have to be an IRC server.

Comment: Yea I'm actually pro opening everything afterwards, I would also encourage doing writeups of the problems and post them on the blog.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

They seem to have merged the teams (good job Antony :)), **so the links below are mostly dead**. The team to join has all three names and can be found [here](http://ctftime.org/team/3585/). I am not yet a member - they didn't merge members, so I can't accept anyone to join :(

---

We have multiple ctftime.org teams :(

- https://ctftime.org/team/4193/
- https://ctftime.org/team/3585/
- https://ctftime.org/team/4011/

**Can we all join one?** Mostly just so we can have a decent total score, and a log of all our challenges. In the interest of me being lazy, I would like to suggest we all join [secse](https://ctftime.org/team/4193/) because then I don't have to do anything, as I am already a member :) **(it also has the highest score so far of the three teams!)**

---

TLDR: go join https://ctftime.org/team/4193/

Comment: I've put in a request with CTFTime to see if we can merge the teams. Will update here when I have an answer.

Comment: You are now a member, welcome back :)

Comment: @AntonyVennard woo thanks, logo uploaded and default name changed :P

Comment: All but #3585 are 404

Answer (score 1):

I can provide a IRC server/ Wiki at a sub domain of my website for the team , I would be interested in being involved but my be constricted by time:
I work as a Linux Sysadmin.
Can program in C and quite well entrenched in Bash.

Comment: I also have an IRC server as well as a Teamspeak3 and/or Mumble server that I can make available on my dedicated server.  My IRC server is part of Dorksnet.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to join too, although I am inexperienced in participating in the competitions I have a very good understanding of networks and protocols that are required.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend documenting what you learn in a way that wont spoil the CTF for future participants. It might even make a nice blog post or series of blog posts.