# ForbiddenBITS CTF 2013

Tags: discussion, ctf

[The Sec.SE CTF team](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team) participated in [ForbiddenBITS CTF 2013](http://ctftime.org/event/68/) as team [secse](http://ctftime.org/team/3585/).

Answer (score 6):

## Nazi War

We can submit a name and get an encrypted password. A little experimentation shows that the password is always the same for a given name, and the encrypted password consists of 13 characters, the first two of which are always `fb`. Furthermore only the first 8 characters of the file name are significant. This looks like a traditional Unix DES password hash.

After logging in, we can read some files but not `flag` which is reserved to “my fuhrer”. Furthermore, if we pick `hitler` as a username, we aren't told what the encrypted password is. So let's find the encrypted password for `hitler`.

Get the encrypted password for some usernames and plug them into a password cracker. I used John the Ripper and waited overnight.

```
cat >passwd <<EOF
a:fbc4G6VBoVf/A:1:1:A:/bin/sh
b:fbN6QGgUKaE2Q:2:2:B:/bin/sh
EOF
john passwd
```

The password of user `a` is `ah4x0r` and the password of user `b` is `bh4x0r`. So the password of user `hitler` must be `hitlerh4x0r` which encrypts to `fboWsVzkSumM.`.

The flag is `99fa57bd69cdcfdd2e2fb6419e2994ca`.

## Invisible

`real.html` is a [Whitespace](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/) program.

The following perl snippet looks for integer constants with at least 3 digits that are pushed on the stack and that are followed by an instruction that ends with a newline. While crude, this is enough to yield the solution.

```
<real.html perl -ne '
    chomp;
    s/^  // or next;
    length >= 3 or next;
    y/ \t/01/; s/^/0b/;
    print chr(oct($_))'
```

The output is `wEsGlHaInJgKThe key is We_are_Nasus     Cwrong`, and the flag is `We_are_Nasus`.

A more precise examination shows that passing `wslang` as input to the program makes it output the flag. The first part of the output of the Perl script above is `wslang` interlaced with jump labels for the comparison code.

## X95

http://forbiddenbits.net/tasks/x95.txt contains a Perl script.

The perl script prints a random integer between 0 and 19 and reads a password. The password is encrypted with the `x0` function using the random integer as a key. The ciphertext is then transliterated and further munged.

The output of `x0` is a string of hexadecimal digits. It is transliterated to a different set of digits:

```
0123456789abcdef
_`abcdefgh234567
```

In the end, we want `$dd` to match

```
^.........................78874.....87897.....98658..87896865978788648788........65859865898659687897.*$
```

perl -le 'print chr for 33..126' | xargs -n1 -d\\n ./encoder1 $str2auth |grep substituted | grep -E --color '78($|8)|( |7)88' finds matches only for str2auth = 7 or 8.

`87897` must come from `E` → `878978`
`98658` must come from `X` → `8658598658598`
`87896` must come from `D` → `878968`
-->

With `$str2auth==8` and `2` transformed to `8` (requires the first character to be below 0x9f), the hex digits after `x0` map to:

```
` 860
_ 859
a 861
b 868
c 863
d 864
e 865
f 878
g 873
h 874
2 88
3 89
4 96
5 97
6 98
7 99
```

So the encoded string must match

```
[........................]fh[.....]f5[.....9]e[8..]f4e5fdf[8.......]e_e3e4f5
```

One possibility is

```
ccccccccfhe2f5f_eaf4e5fdf2cce_e3e4f5
```

which we then translate back to the usual hex digits, xor with `$str2auth`, and to the string

```
DDDDyj}pb|muzD`kl}
||||AREHZDUMB|XSTE
```

We're almost there, but we can't have a lone `X`. Fortunately we can pick the character before the `X`. Before X doubling:

```
XXAREHZDUMBXSTE
```

Try it online a few times (there's a 1/20 chance that the script will draw 8 as the auth key each time), and soon enough:

```
$ print -l 8 XXArEHZDUMBXSTE | nc 192.73.237.148 3002
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-++-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 _    _  95   _________   ______   ______  _    _  _____  ______   ______ 
\ \  / /     | | | | | \ | |  | | | |     | |  | |  | |  | |  \ \ | |     
 >|--|<      | | | | | | | |__| | | |     | |--| |  | |  | |  | | | |---- 
/_/  \_\     |_| |_| |_| |_|  |_| |_|____ |_|  |_| _|_|_ |_|  |_| |_|____ 

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-++-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+




Password : 


FLAG{PERL_IS_COOL_FOR_SCRIPTING}
```

## Fantasy

These are runes from *Star Wars*, specifically the [Aurebesh script](http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20071202200436/starwars/images/thumb/c/cc/Aurebesh-GMSR.png/640px-Aurebesh-GMSR.png). They spell `starwarsiscool`.

Comment: thanks for sharing it, it serve as an inspiration to new users