# EBCTF: Fri 2 August 10:00 UTC, lasts 36 hours

Tags: discussion, ctf

Let's participate in the [EBCFT CTF 2013](http://ebctf.nl/) as [team Sec.SE](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team).

> After almost two years of fanatically playing in CTF competitions ourselves, the moment has finally come... Eindbazen is organizing their own CTF!
>
> We invite all of you to come play our CTF titled "ebCTF" held during the biggest quadrennial (every 4 years) Dutch hacker gathering OHM2013 (predecessors are HIP1997, HAL2001, WTH2005 and HAR2009). For the unfortunate ones who cannot make it to the camping site in the Netherlands we of course offer the ability to play online/remotely as well!
>
> Eindbazen will be hosting the competition live from the camping site. You can come and work on hacking challenges in our ebCTF hideout, from your own tent.. or maybe even from a very distant remote location! The only requirement is a working internet connection. Of course you can also just come hang out at the ebCTF hideout, meet up with other CTF/security enthousiasts, have a drink... and plan world domination together! (…)
>
> We're very much looking forward to provide you with a unique and genuine CTF experience during ebCTF and would like to stress again that the "full experience" can only be had on-site, at OHM2013 (July 31 - 4 August 2013). So do not hesitate any further and start planning your vacation to the Netherlands right NOW!
>
> For questions or comments, please come visit us on IRC in #ebctf on freenode.

As usual, the team communicates through the [CTF team chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7384/security-se-ctf-team). Shortly before the competition, the room will be switched to private and the team password will be posted to the room. Participation is open to anyone with [participation on Security Stack Exchange or related Stack Exchange sites](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team) — ping one of us on the [meta post](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team) or in the [DMZ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151) to request access.

We participated in the [teaser round](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/ebctf-teaser-1st-june-midday-utc) in June as team secse. We [came](http://ebctf.nl/scoreboard?page=3) 69th with only 2 challenges solved. Let's do better this time!

Answer (score 5):

[image]