# DIMVA CTF: starts Wed 17 July 18:00 GMT

Tags: discussion, ctf

[DIMVA Capture The Flag](https://dimvactf.0x90.eu/index.html) starts Wednesday 17 July at 18:00 GMT and lasts 44 hours. Some highlights from the rules:

> - This is a level-based CTF, there is no attack and defense and it has challenges of different levels so anybody can enjoy playing it.
> - The CTF is designed to be played individually. Nevertheless we know we cannot avoid teams playing too.
> - Sharing solutions between different users is not allowed and will result in disqualification, play as a team then.
>
> Join the #dimvactf IRC channel on [hackint](http://www.hackint.eu/) for realtime communication.

If you want to play as a team, you can join [team Sec.SE](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team) (see the meta post for more information). We meet in the [CTF team chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7384/security-se-ctf-team).

If you prefer to play alone (which is necessary to win any prize), do not join the room.

Comment: I'd love to participate in these, but generally the notice period is short. Can we get towards giving a month+ notice on CTFs? Even a week?

Comment: @JeffFerland I'd like that too. I'm usually not the one who watches for announcements, I just post them on meta. We did announce [this week-end's CTF](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/ufo-ctf-2013-july-19-21-2013-1800-utc4) more than a week in advance.

Comment: @JeffFerland p____h noticed this one when it was close to starting. We thought that we might as well play it :)

Answer (score 3):

### Crypto 100

We have some plaintext files (`quote?.txt`) and what is presumably the associated ciphertext, plus `empty.png` and `flag.png`, in the form of PNG image. A quick look at the PNG files (e.g. conversion to PBM) shows that they are all grayscale and have identical grayscale values. The next obvious thing to try is the alpha channels.

```
for x in *.png; do pngtopnm -alpha <$x >${x%.*}.alpha; done
```

The alpha channels consist of bytes `\xff` and `\xfb` (except `empty.png` which is all zero), with the trailing bytes being `\xff`. Let's pack them into 8-bit bytes. I initially chose `\xff` to be the 0, but it turns out to be 1.

```
for x in *.alpha; do perl -we '
    scalar <> for 1..3;
    $line = <>;
    while ($line =~ s/^(........)//) {
        $_=$1; y/\xff\xfb/10/;
        $buf .= chr(oct("0b$_"))
    }
    $buf =~ s/\0+$//; print $buf
' <$x >${x%.*}.enc; done
```

The resulting `quote?.enc` files are identical to the corresponding plaintext files `quote?.txt` (except for some trailing `\xff` padding). In `flag.enc`, we see (encoded in UTF-8)

```
Here's your flag, enjoy :-): ⓒ⓪ⓕⓕⓔⓔ⑦⑤②ⓑ③②⑦⑧⑤ⓕ③①ⓓⓒ⑤⑦ⓕ①ⓔ⑨ⓒ③ⓕ⑧⓪ⓔ
```

For the Unicode-challenged, these are [enclosed alphanumerics](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2460.pdf), U+2460 through U+24FF. The flag is `c0ffee752b32785f31dc57f1e9c3f80e`.

There was no cryptography here, only steganography.

Answer (score 2):

### Misc 200

We have an XDP file which encodes a PDF file. At the bottom of the PDF file is a comment with the password of the PDF file. [p____h](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/10414/p-h) provided a decompressed version. There's a string in there that looks like a flag, but this isn't it. There's also some Javascript code, encoded with hexadecimal escapes. Here it is after some light reformatting.

```
var resp = app.response({cQuestion:"Enter password", cTitle:"Password",});
if (resp == this.saveXML()) {
    var s = "c0ffeed5838de68871c45374f04c865a";
    var t = "" + this.resolveNode("/flagKey");
    var n = "c0ffee";
    var baz = 0;
    for (var i=6; i<s.length; i+=2) {
        baz = parseInt(s.substr(i,2),16) ^ t.charCodeAt(i/2-3);
        a = baz.toString(16);
        if (a.length == 1) {
            n += "0" + a
        } else {
            n += a
        }
    }
    this.rawValue = n
} else {
    app.alert("Incorrect password")
}
```

`flagKey` is `CXrgfTA4sBXz9SBehVirA4A61zOgkXbm`. Executing this JavaScript code (minus password check) with `t` set to the `flagKey` field of the XFA data yields `c0ffee96dbff81ee25856707b214fc63`, which is still not the flag.
(Or is `flagKey` encoded in Base64? That produces `c0ffeedcf96d9bb849744687056cd8df` which isn't correct either.)

After the contest ended, with [HamZa](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/25859/hamza), we realized that `this.resolveNode("/flagKey")` returns `null` (which makes sense: there's no node called `/flagKey`). With `t="null"`, we get the correct flag value: `c0ffeebbf6e18a8871c45374f04c865a`.

Running the code in Acrobat Reader (which I didn't want to bother installing for the contest) also works, if you change the code to omit the password check.