# ASIS-CTF: starts Thu 29 August 13:30 UTC, lasts 48 hours

Tags: discussion, ctf

Let's participate in the [ASIS CTF](http://asis-ctf.ir/en/) as [team Sec.SE](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team).

> What is it all about?
>
> There are many contests around the world named CTF, Attack-Defence or Cyber Security; ASIS-CTF is one of them! ASIS-CTF is Task-based (Jeopardy) and the questions is organised in these categories:
>
> - General security information (trivia)
> - Web hacking
> - Cryptography protocols and implementations
> - Security of software systems
> - Digital forensics
> - Reverse engineering
> - Steganography
> - Misc
>
> ASIS-CTF 2013 will be available online for every one, and the contest will begin on Aug 29, 2013 18:00 IRDT and lasts for 48 hours. (be careful, every time that we announce is in IRDT time zone) are you ready for [registration](http://asis-ctf.ir/en/register)? or want to read the [rules](http://asis-ctf.ir/en/rules) first.

As usual, the team communicates through the [CTF team chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7384/security-se-ctf-team). Shortly before the competition, the room will be switched to private and the team password will be posted to the room. Participation is open to anyone with [participation on Security Stack Exchange or related Stack Exchange sites](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team) — ping one of us on the [meta post](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team) or in the [DMZ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151) to request access.