# Ghost in the Shellcode CTF started Fri 17 Jan 20:30 UTC, lasts 46 hours

Tags: discussion, ctf

[Ghost in the Shellcode](http://ghostintheshellcode.com/) 2014 will be running from Friday 17 January 2014 at 20:30 UTC to Sunday 19 January 2014 at 18:30 UTC. Let's participate as team Sec.SE.

You can see [archives of previous years](http://ghostintheshellcode.com/2013-index.html).

---

As usual, the team communicates through the [CTF team chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7384/security-se-ctf-team). Shortly before the competition, the room will be switched to private and the team password will be posted to the room. Participation is open to anyone with [participation on Security Stack Exchange or related Stack Exchange sites](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team) — ping one of us on the [meta post](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team) or in the [DMZ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151) to request access.

Comment: I probably can show up. Will need a reminder ping though.

Comment: Popped this on featured for a bit :-)

Comment: I would like to participate. I just put in the request for the team on CTFtime.org. I've also asked a question on the chat since I hadn't heard anything.

Comment: @DigitalFire “We participate” means “at least one person registers and participates, and posts the credentials in the chat room (after verifying that it's private)”.