# Ghost in the Shellcode CTF - starts 08 jan 2016 at 20:00 UTC and lasts ~33h

Tags: discussion, ctf

[Ghost in the Shellcode](http://ghostintheshellcode.com) will begin on 08 January 2016 20:00 UTC and ends on 10 January 2016 04:59 UTC.

Let's play as [team Sec.SE](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team). As usual, the team communicates through the [CTF team chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7384/security-se-ctf-team).

Comment: Hmmm. I just read on the site "Ghost in the Shellcode 2016 has been postponed. Sorry everyone! We'll announce a new date later this year.".