# IceCTF 2016 - Fri, 12 Aug 2016, 16:00 UTC, lasts two weeks

Tags: discussion, ctf

Let's participate at [IceCTF 2016](https://icec.tf).

The CTF will begin on Friday 12 August 2016 16:00 UTC and ends two weeks later on 26 August 2016 20:30 UTC.

As usual, we will play as [team sec.se](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team). The team communicates through the [CTF team chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7384/security-se-ctf-team).

An excerpt from [ctftime](https://ctftime.org/event/319):

> IceCTF is a computer security contest targeted at anyone with an interest in computer science. The game consists of a series of challenges where participants must reverse engineer, break, hack, decrypt, or do whatever it takes to solve the challenge. The challenges are all set up with the intent of being hacked, making it a great way to get some hands-on experience. IceCTF is designed to accommodate both novice and advanced players alike. Many challenges will guide you to the right resources. As long as you're willing to learn and do a little research, most challenges should be within reach.

Which means all levels should have some fun.

I will register a team on the website and share the required information to join the team in the CTF chatroom.

Comment: I don't have 400 rep on Information Security stackexchange but I spectacularly meet all the other requirements. Can I still participate? 1. advanced understanding of security topics 2. several programming languages 3. over 3500 reputation on related sites 4. TCP/IP + UDP

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC check the CTF chatroom ;_)

Comment: @HamZa The chat room is blocked, is there somewhere else that I am supposed to go in order to join?

Comment: @HamZa heads up: I won't be participating with you guys in the team. going lone wolf

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry for intervening, but here are a few quotes from their [FAQ](https://icec.tf/faq):

Q: "How many people can be on a team?"

A: "Teams can consist of **1-3 contestants**."

---

Q: "Can I create more than 1 team?"

A: "**No**. There is no point in creating multiple accounts. Teams found with duplicated accounts will be disqualified."

---

Q: "What is defined as cheating?"

A: "...**but specifically asking people on the internet to help you solve the problem is cheating"**

---

Therefore, I believe that having a Security Exchange team, while a terrific idea, is considered as cheating and will result in the disqualification of all participating users.
Instead, I think it's best that the big team splits into smaller teams and each team works alone to ensure the legitimacy of their score :)

Comment: Nice catch! My bad for not seeing this. That said, one of the "major" problems is that we don't have separate private chat rooms. So how do you suggest to communicate while having a persistent server side archival of our messages, privacy and a service we trust?

Comment: Isn't it possible to ask a moderator to open a few chat rooms?

Comment: no, *private* chatrooms are meant for moderators and developers of StackExchange. The current chatroom we have is already an exception to the rule. We also happen to have had a small problem with it last few weeks because it wasn't designed for us to use.

Comment: From their registration page: "In order to be eligible for prizes, all members of your team must be Icelandic residents, and you must not have more than three team members. If you do not meet these requirements, you are still welcome to play, but you will not be eligible for prizes." This implies that you are allowed to have more then three people.

Comment: Also I believe that the Internet faq involves asking things like SE, not working with your team.

Comment: Participating as a team is not “asking people on the internet to help you solve the problem”. This isn't cheating, teams are allowed, this is quite standard for CTF. The limitation to 3 people teams is unusual and I don't know what to do about that. I don't even know if we'll have more than 3 actual participants. The CTF we usually do last about 2 days, not 2 weeks.

Comment: @AstroDan no where does it allow you to participate with more than three members. It simply states that you're still welcome to play even though you're ineligible for a prize if you live outside of Iceland.

Comment: @Tom From their registration page: "In order to be eligible for prizes, all members of your team must be Icelandic residents, and you must not have more than three team members. If you do not meet these requirements, you are still welcome to play, but you will not be eligible for prizes." https://play.icec.tf/register/

Comment: @AstroDan you're still interpreting it wrong. Being ineligible for prizes doesn't give you the right to cheat.