# Google CTF 2017, 17 June 2017 at 00:00 UTC, lasts 48 hours

Tags: discussion, ctf

Let's participate in [Google CTF 2017](https://capturetheflag.withgoogle.com/).

The CTF will begin on 17 June 2017 00:00:01 UTC and ends on 18 June 2017 23:59:59 UTC.

As usual, we will play as [team sec.se](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team), but unlike previous CTFs, because of StackExchange changes on private chatrooms, we'll use Slack as our communication medium.

Please join [the public chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz) to request an invite and to join the team.

---

We solved a total of 6 challenges worth 943 points in total. We got the 54th place out of the 1977 teams. Good job everyone!

Comment: Is this happening? Quite happy to join the team if so I have a free weekend this week.

Comment: @TheJulyPlot Currently we are 5 players, so this is definitely happening. Feel free to join!

Comment: You should link to an explanation of the chat room changes you are referring to.

Comment: What is the Slack team? I thought it was `ctf.sec.se` but there's nobody there.

Comment: The Slack is at https://sec-ctf.slack.com/

Comment: Awww, got here a few days too late :(

Comment: @FilipHaglund secse team will probably play some more ctf in the coming weeks, stay tuned :)