# SECUINSIDE CTF 2017, 01 July 00:00 - 02 July 7:33 AM UTC

Tags: discussion, ctf

Are you ready for another crazy CTF with [sec.se](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team) team?

We will participate in the [Secuinside CTF](http://secuinside.com/2017/ctf.html).

There are no indications about the challenge categories. Howewer, according to [last year write-ups](https://github.com/ctfs/write-ups-2016/tree/master/secuinside-ctf-quals-2016), we can expect: `cgc, misc, pwnable, web`.

We will communicate through Slack. To get an invitation, please send me an e-mail (you can find my address on my profile) with your security.stackexchange name. Once you're on the Slack, you will find instructions to register and join the team.

For additional information, you can also [join us on the public chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz).

Comment: Absolutely great to see the sec.se team compete regularly again!