# PoliCTF 2017 | Fri, 07 July, 09:00 – Sun, 09 July, 09:00 UTC

Tags: discussion, ctf

Let's participate in the [PoliCTF 2017](http://www.polictf.it/)!

PoliCTF a **Jeopardy**-style CTF running in its third edition and lasts 48h. There are currently [100+ participating teams](https://ctftime.org/event/425) announced on CTFtime.

Basic info:

- We will compete as [team sec.se](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team).
- The team communicates [over Slack](http://sec-ctf.slack.com/). To get an invitation to the group you can contact [Benoit Esnard](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/76718/benoit-esnard), [HamZa](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/25859/hamza), [Xavier59](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/110133/xavier59), [Arminius](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/95381/arminius) or any other active team member. (We will need to know an email address you want registered and a reference to your Security.SE profile.)
- For questions, join us in the [public chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz).

Good luck everyone!