# HackIT CTF 2017 | Fri, 25 Aug, 14:00 – Sun, 27 Aug, 14:00 UTC

Tags: discussion, ctf

Let's participate in the **[HackIT CTF 2017](https://ctf.com.ua/)**!

HackIT is a **Jeopardy**-style CTF and lasts 48 hours with 100+ participating teams announced. You can find additional details on the CTFtime [event page](https://ctftime.org/event/491) and study the write-ups of the 2016 edition [here](https://ctftime.org/event/360/tasks/).

General info:

- We compete as team [secse](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stackexchange-ctf-team).
- We communicate over [Slack](http://sec-ctf.slack.com/). To get an invitation to the group you can contact [Benoit Esnard](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/76718/benoit-esnard), [HamZa](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/25859/hamza), [Xavier59](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/110133/xavier59), [Arminius](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/95381/arminius) or any other active team member. (We will need to know an email address to send the invitation to and a reference to your Security.SE profile.)
- For questions, join us in the [public chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz).

Good luck everyone!

Comment: +1 - i'll be in.

Comment: The first link is either broken or hacked. It shows the empty Apache index page.

Comment: @kenorb Well, the CTF is done, so they put their site down. I think I'll just leave the link there. For reference you can look at the [CTFtime event](https://ctftime.org/event/491).