# HITCON CTF 2018 | Sat, 20 Oct 02:00 — Mon, 22 Oct 02:00 UTC (48h)

Tags: discussion, ctf

Let's participate in the [HITCON CTF 2018](https://ctftime.org/event/669)!

- **Format:** Jeopardy
- **Duration:** 48h
- **Start:** Sat, 2018-10-20 02:00 UTC <sup>[(Other timezone)](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=HITCON+CTF+2018&iso=20181020T020000)</sup>
- **Finish:** Mon, 2018-10-22 02:00 UTC <sup>[(Other timezone)](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=HITCON+CTF+2018&iso=20181022T020000)</sup>
- **Official URL:** https://ctf.hitcon.org/
- **CTFtime URL:** https://ctftime.org/event/669
- **Rating weight:** 98.32 <sup>[(?)](https://ctftime.org/faq/#weight)</sup>
- **Organizers:** [217](https://ctftime.org/team/5160), [HITCON](https://ctftime.org/team/8299)
- **Event series:** [HITCON CTF](https://ctftime.org/ctf/79)

General info:

- We compete as team [secse](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117/).
- We communicate over [Slack](http://sec-ctf.slack.com/). To get an invitation
  to the workspace you can contact any active team member. (We will need to
  know an email address to send the invitation to and a reference to your
  Security.SE profile.)
- For questions, join us in the [public chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz).

Good luck everyone!

Comment: Wow! This site even features CTF events!