# Square CTF | 08 Nov. 2018, 19:00 UTC —14 Nov. 2018, 19:00 UTC

Tags: discussion, ctf

Let's participate in the [Square CTF](https://ctftime.org/event/695)!

- **Format:** Jeopardy
- **Duration:** 6 days(!)
- **Start:** Thu, 2018-11-08 19:00 UTC <sup>[(Other timezone)](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=Square+CTF+2018&iso=20181108T190000)</sup>
- **Finish:** Mon, 2018-11-14 19:00 UTC <sup>[(Other timezone)](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=HITCON+CTF+2018&iso=20181114T190000)</sup>
- **Official URL:** http://squarectf.com
- **CTFtime URL:** https://ctftime.org/event/695
- **Rating weight:** 25,00 <sup>[(?)](https://ctftime.org/faq/#weight)</sup>
- **Organizers:** [squareCTF](https://ctftime.org/team/63648)

General info:

- We compete as team [secse](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117/).
- We communicate over [Slack](http://sec-ctf.slack.com/). To get an invitation
  to the workspace you can contact any active team member. (We will need to
  know an email address to send the invitation to and a reference to your
  Security.SE profile.)
- For questions, join us in the [public chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz).

Good luck everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Team secse finished place 117 out of 595 participants. Thanks for competing everyone!