# Community Promotion Ads — 2019

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2019 is here! And with the new year, as usual, comes a new iteration of **Community Promotion Ads**! Let’s refresh these for the coming year :)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- useful or cool security related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3144).

Comment: We do have a [CtF team](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/a-security-stack-exchange-ctf-team) here and I'd love to promote it via an ad - and I'm sure other people would vote for that as well, right?! But unfortunately we do not have a logo or anything else that is "convertable to image" (so to speak). Is it possible to employ the fabulous SE designer that created the site logo for this task?

Comment: @TomK. Can we use the "Do all the challenges!" image that is on your link? I would totally vote to put that image up as an ad on stackoverflow, and not just ironically :)

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about the copyright legalities but I guess that's up to @JNat. I wouldn't disagree. Maybe the other peeps from the CtF team could chime in as well.

Answer (score 13):

[image: EFF - The leading nonprofit defending digital privacy, free speech, and innovation]

Answer (score 6):

[image: @StackSecurity]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 4):

[image: Security Without Borders]

Comment: It is not updated very often, apparently?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul What is not updated?

Comment: The blog got 2 posts in 2019 and 0 posts in 2018. If another section of the website is more relevant, you can consider linking to it :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul The link is to the front page, as it should be, which happend to host a not so often updated newsfeed.